# My None check is not working keep getting "NoneType object has no attribute XXX"

Tags: python, jython, maximo

I have encountered this error before. It usually means that I am trying to use and method with an empty object. So I put in checks but the checks do not seem to be working. Here is my code:

```
    possiblechildSet= MXServer.getMXServer().getMboSet("ASSETANCESTOR", userinfo)
    possiblechildSet.setWhere("ANCESTOR='" mbo.getString("ASSETNUM") "' and ASSETNUM !='" mbo.getString("ASSETNUM") "'")
    if (possiblechildSet.count() <> 0) or (possiblechildSet.count() is not None) :
        childSet= mbo.getMboSet("ASSETMISSINGCHILD")
        if childSet.count() is not None:
            childMbo = childSet.getMbo(0)
            childassetnum = childMbo.getString('ASSETNUM') //error
```

I am getting the error when i attempt to use the getString method. Which is valid. I have used in this way in multiple scripts before hand. I just don't understand how it is getting through my checks.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks
Wann

Comment: What is the actual attribute error you're receiving?

Comment: thank you for replying. the error im getting is AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getString' in <script> at line number 26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the check on the next line:

```
childMbo = childSet.getMbo(0)
if childMbo is not None:
    childassetnum = childMbo.getString('ASSETNUM')
```

Comment: That worked Thank you! If you have the time would you mind explaining why it wasn't happening before?

Comment: It is always better to check the exact thing you need: here you want to know if childMbo  is None, so test for that. 
I don't know why "childSet.count() is not None " wasn't working, maybe it was returning 0, maybe it is a special case where childSet.count() and childSet.getMbo(0) are not related.